# Animate image as progress indicator. (ios)

Tags: ios, animation

I have an image (see image), and I want the outer ring to dissolve clockwise - piece by piece. So the outer ring would decrease in length in proportion with the amount of video played. This outer ring would basically be a progress indicator,

For example, at 50% of video played there would be just half of the outer ring being displayed.  Is there a way to animate this using an image?

[image]

Comment: create .gif image and load this image in webview and add webview as  transparent on any view. For creating gif use any online tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `CAShapeLayer` to do that or you can use an array of `UIImage`

I hope this helps